# How can I remove the first part of a file path in a hash file?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have a hash file, example.md5, full of hashes and file names similar to the following.

```
e5dbb7657f770fad038220f5c69d806c  backup/example/test.txt
```

How could I batch edit that file to instead look like.

```
e5dbb7657f770fad038220f5c69d806c  example/test.txt
```

I just want to remove the first part of each file path mentioned in the hash file.

EDIT: includes some numbers in file paths, i.e. `e5dbb7657f770fad038220f5c69d806c  750g/example/test.txt`

Comment: You can use `awk` as well: `awk  '{split($2,a,"/"); $2=a[2]"/"a[3]}1' file`, $2 means the second column and the default field separator(FS) is " ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **GNU** `sed`:

```
sed -E -n 's/([a-z0-9]+)( *)[A-Za-z0-9]+\/(.*)/\1\2\3/p' file_name
```

Output:

```
e5dbb7657f770fad038220f5c69d806c  example/test.txt
```

Explanation:

```
-E : --regexp-extended(using extended regular expressions)

-n : --quiet, --silent, suppress automatic printing of pattern space

([a-z0-9]+) : Capturing first group containing the hash characters which includes a combination of one or more small alphabets and numbers

( *) : capturing second group containing whitespaces

[A-Za-z0-9]+\ : matching the first part of second column which may be a combination of one or more small alphabets,numbers and capital letters and a \


(.*) : cpaturing the third group containing any character.

\1\2\3 : backreferencing the first,second and third captured groups.

/p : to print
```

Comment: Is there a missing single quote?  That command as is will not run on my system

Comment: this trips over lines with numbers.  This line  `365846d4a15ab600d77f46b2f37f5764 750gb/test.log.txt` became `365846d4a15ab600d77f46b2f37f5764 750gtest.log.txt`

Comment: @RansuDoragon: As per your sample input in the question , i thought the first part in second column would contain only small alphabets, have updated my answer now.

Comment: I'll update that. I should have been more clear, sorry. Thank you for the help, above sed command works for me.    I should also probably try to learn what I can about sed and the like since I am getting more into command line stuff.

Comment: This is just a too-complex variation of rɑːdʒɑ's answer.

Comment: @tripleee: yeah, me too found rɑːdʒɑ's answer easy :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below sed

```
[root@967dd7743677 test]# sed 's:[a-z]*/::' hashfile
e5dbb7657f770fad038220f5c69d806c  example/test.txt
[root@967dd7743677 test]#
```

Comment: `s:[^/]*/::` instead of `s:[a-z]*/::` would work even if the directory names contained digits, uppercase letters or other characters...

Comment: @Dario, but it will omit column1, seems op wanted along with column1.

[root@967dd7743677 test]# sed 's:[^/]*/::' hashfile
example/test.txt
[root@967dd7743677 test]#

Comment: `sed 's:[0-9][a-z]*/::' hashfile`   Seems to have worked here. Some lines had numbers in the first part of the path, i.e.  3tb/backup/test.txt

Comment: No actually that didn't work, sorry. It seems to have tripped over lines like `750gb/backup/test.txt`  turning it into `75/backup/test.txt`

Comment: You want to combine that into a single class - `sed 's:[-0-9a-z_]*/::' hashfile` (I added dash and underscore for good measure).